# Screen share for remote assistance for Windows environment

Tags: windows, screen-sharing

I'm looking for some free software that can help to connect remote computer and let user use the  keyboard and mouse, I'm looking for something like AnyDesk or Teamviewer but not like RDP where users on both end can't see what's going on.

I tried using Windows Quick Assistant but did not work for me.

Comment: *like AnyDesk or Teamviewer*, and why indeed not those two? Those two are probably the most popular and work well.

Comment: I'm using free version and they are not working for me.

Comment: Windows Quick Assistant "did not work", AnyDesk or Teamviewer "are not working". But You don't explain in which way they all aren't working for you. Can you be more clear? It will also help if you explain the type of usage (like, is it you accessing one/two of your own devices, or you logging in to a bunch of different devices?)

Comment: I was working with someone who is in different country, We tried a lot to connect through all these software but not luck, now we used zoom meeting and we were able to share the screen, as i had no idea why it was not working upon many tries that's why i totally left it and i was looking for some alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three more (from known reputable companies, and for free) to try (though without knowing the issues with the others we have no way of knowing if those will work):

1. [**Chrome Remote Desktop**](https://remotedesktop.google.com/?pli=1)
2. [**ConnectWise Control**](https://control.connectwise.com/) (*see [here](https://docs.connectwise.com/ConnectWise_Control_Documentation/Get_started/ConnectWise_Control_Free/Add_a_Free_license_to_your_instance) how to apply a free license*)
3. [**Zoho Assist**](https://www.zoho.com/assist/)